# Не работает клавиатура и черный экран Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, suspend

Здравствуйте у меня такая проблема, что при включении ноутбука когда загружается Ubuntu я не могу ввести пароль из-за того что не работает клавиатура(3-4 кнопки работают FN, F3, F4, F5) приходится перезагрузить. При этом когда с первого раза захожу в БИОС там всё окей. И ещё одна проблема в том что после закрытие крышки или после перехода в спящий режим у меня просто черный экран. В чём проблема если ли какое-то решение я обновил всё что предлагал Ubuntu при этом я захожу в БИОС закрываю крышку открываю всё окей.